# What's the sense of Windows Service Dependencies?

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, windows-server-2016, windows-services

I have created a computer program, which I have installed as a Windows service, and I have added a dependency towards another Windows service, the "KEPServerEX 6.9 Runtime", as you can see from this screenshot:

[image]

I have tested this dependency in different ways:

1. I have restarted my computer and I tried to verify that "KEPServerEX 6.9 Runtime" is started up earlier than my program.
2. I have stopped "KEPServerEX 6.9 Runtime" and I expected my program to be stopped too.

These are my results:

1. No idea: when my program starts, and entry is created in the event log. This is not the case for "KEPServerEX 6.9 Runtime", neither does "KEP..." create loggings, so I have no idea where or not this test succeeded.
2. My program did not stop.

Even if I manage proving that my program only starts up after "KEPServerEX 6.9 Runtime" when rebooting my computer, I wonder (seeing point 2) what's the sense of Windows Service dependencies.

I'm working on a Windows-10 computer, while my customer is working with Windows Server 2016. I would like the answers to be valid for both operating systems.

For your information: "KEPServerEX 6.9 Runtime" is a commercial tool, I am not able to modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Microsoft's
[sc.exe config](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sc-config) :

> depend= `<dependencies>`
>
> Specifies the names of services or groups that must start before this
> service. The names are separated by forward slashes (/).

That's the only reason for dependencies - putting some order into
the Windows startup process.

After startup, the dependencies have no effect, except when restarting
the dependent service.

Comment: you say "... except when restarting the dependent service", but this is exactly what I did: I have restarted "KEPServer" but my program did not stop or restart, hence my question.

Comment: You restarted KEPServerEX, but this doesn't affect your program, since you didn't try to restart it. Only startup is affected, not shutdown.